# Apple sells toys in their store?

Tags: apple-store, accessories

I was thinking what intresting in their website and when i looked for everything i found toys! Heres a picture i noticed [image: TOYS???]

Why would apple sell toys if they just are tech company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are tech-enabled toys made by Disney as part of their **Disney Infinity** line. These toys can interact with specific apps on Apple devices.   This is similar to Apple selling drones that can be controlled via iPhones.

Disney has recently announced they're discontinuing this line of toys so Apple is probably trying to sell them all and reduce their stock.